# Const Functions and Interfaces in C++

Tags: c++, interface, const-correctness, member-functions

I'll use the following (trivial) interface as an example:

```
struct IObject
{
  virtual ~IObject() {}

  virtual std::string GetName() const = 0;
  virtual void ChangeState() = 0;
};
```

Logic dictates that `GetName` should be a `const` member function while `ChangeState` shouldn't.

All code that I've seen so far doesn't follow this logic, though. That is, `GetName` in the example above wouldn't be marked as a `const` member function.

Is this laziness/carelessness or is there a legitimate reason for this? What are the major cons of me forcing my clients to implement `const` member functions when they are logically called for?

---

**EDIT:** Thanks for your responses everyone. I think it's pretty much unanimous: laziness/ignorance is the reason for what I'm seeing.

Comment: incompetence/laziness/carelessness

Comment: Don't forget ignorance - the prime cause for bad code in my experience.

Comment: @Neil: unfortunately I must agree... I'm in a mood for a rant now :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's laziness/carelessness. `GetName()` should have no effect on the object's state, and the contract of `IObject` should state that fact explicitly.

If the inheriting class was somehow forced to make `GetName()` have (hidden!) side effects, they could always declare the corresponding fields as `mutable`.

Comment: I think people forget that 'const' isn't meant to say that nothing about the internal state of the object should change, but that nothing about the external state should.  I should be able to store a copy of an instance, call the const function, and the original and copy should still compare equal.  Assuming equality actually means equality anything else can change.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: Also imagine thinks like caches. Changing a cache does not change the external state and is safe in const methods.

Comment: @EdwardStrange yes, but the compiler doesn't care about that and that's one major problem with const in C++, binary constness vs. semantic constness. Applying mutables is then sometimes more a patchwork rug than a real robust solution.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this laziness/carelessness or is there a legitimate reason for this?

The former. *If you really haven't seen any code which does this right, **get a new job immediately**.*

> What are the major cons of me forcing my clients to implement `const`member functions when they are logically called for?

It allows the compiler to discover common bugs ***at compile-time***. (Nothing better than errors discovered at compile-time. Everything that fails on your desk, won't fail at the client's site.)

---

More than ten years ago, shortly after I joined a new company and got to hacking at one of their projects, I found that a method that should have been `const` wasn't, preventing some of my `const`-correct code to compile. I considered just casting my `const` away and get on, but I couldn't myself bring to do this.
So I made the method `const` - just to discover that it called other methods, which should have been const, too, but weren't either. So I changed them as well - just to discover...
In the end, I spent several days hunting through all of the project, adding `const` left and right.
Co-workers laughed at me - until I showed them some of the bugs the compiler had discovered due to me adding `const`. Interestingly, a few long-standing bugs nobody had ever taken the time to thoroughly investigate were not reproducible anymore either, after that.

Comment: +1 There is nothing more soul destroying than retro-fitting const correctness to non const correct code.

Comment: @Neil, so right - the cascading effects turn into a waterfall of sorrow.

Comment: I think we've all been there.

Comment: I wish I could give you another +1 just for the war story.

Answer (score 1):

While I think the "laziness" answer is probably right in your case, I do just want to make the point that sometimes a single `const` keyword is not expressive enough to capture the details of mutability of your class.

Consider:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    bool operator==(const MyClass &other) const {
        return identity == other.identity;
    }

    void setVisible(bool vis) { gfx.setVisible(vis); }
    bool isVisible() const;

    // other methods ...

private:
    string identity;
    GraphicsData gfx;
}
```

I think this code is reasonable:

```
MyClass item = ...
item.setVisible(true);

// I want to call a function and be sure that the object's
// visibility did not change, so pass a const ref.
const MyClass &constRef = item;
someSafeFunction(constRef);
```

But at the same time, I think this code is reasonable, too:

```
// Imagine an appropriate std::hash<MyClass> has been
// defined, based on MyClass::identity.
unordered_set<MyClass> set = ...

// Hide some items
for (MyClass &item : set) {
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

However, that second bit of code will not compile, because `unordered_set` can only give `const` references to its contents ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qAaVHm)).
This is because a modification to the object could change its hash code, invalidating its location in the container.

So in effect, `unordered_set` demands that `operator==` and `const` are referring to the same notion of identity.
But that's not what we want in our first use case.

The problem is that our code has two notions of "did the object change", which both make sense from different points of view.

But there is only one `const` keyword you can apply, so you have to pick one, and the other case will suffer.